# jquery tokeinput, what q parameter for php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i used plugin tokeninput of loopj for my list from php/mysql.

But i don't know like used "q" parameter.

This is my html file that use plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("../categorieautocomplete.php", {
        theme: "facebook"
    });
});
```

Anyone has solved this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of things like:

- Hello!
- Hello World!
- Hi There!
- World!

And you send `?q=H` to the PHP, it should return only:

- Hello!
- Hello World!
- Hi There!

And for `?q=He`, it should return only:

- Hello!
- Hello World!

From the [documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/):

> Your script must accept a GET parameter named q which will contain the term to search for. E.g. http://www.example.com/myscript?q=query
>
> Your script should output JSON search results in the following format:
>
> ```
> [
>     {"id":"856","name":"House"},
>     {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
>     ...
> ]
> ```

Comment: Thank's for you answer, so i change my script in : $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("../categorieautocomplete.php?q=he", {
        theme: "facebook"
    });
});

Comment: Yes.. You need to change it accordingly!

Comment: But from the long list for different result, like i can do this ? I suppose i need generate automatically "?q=He". But i don't undestarstand where

Comment: You can actually use the MySQL query `LIKE '%{$q}%'`. Something on that way!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solve this in this way :

in my HTML file associate "q" to $modify :

```
<input type='text' id='demo-input-facebook-theme' name=modify />
    <script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function() { $('#demo-input-facebook-theme').tokenInput('categorieautocomplete.php?q=$modify', { theme: 'facebook' ,
```

and into my PHP file change query in :

```
$query = ("SELECT ID,CATEGORIA from INTUITcategoria WHERE CATEGORIA LIKE '%{$q}%' ORDER BY categoria");
```

Thank' a lot to all.

Best Regards.

Stefano